# Internal Python application and Python packages with multiple licenses

Tags: gpl-3, apache-2.0, lgpl, mpl, python

I am developing a tool for internal use in my company using Python and several Python packages.

This tool uses different kinds of Python packages, all of which have one of GNU Public License, Lesser GNU Public License, Apache 2.0 license, BSD-3 license, MIT license or MPL 2.0 license.

I have checked that everything is free to use for commercial use, which took a long time, and I have already added a copy of all the licenses to the internal distribution, stating that for licenses that require to state changes, the repository contains the track history with every change introduced. This is all visible in the help files, under the licensing section.

I am concerned about the copyleft side of these clauses, I understand that as long as the tool remains internal and the code available for everyone to use or modify, there is no breach of these licenses.

If this tool is ever distributed outside of the company, due to licensing of third-party packages the source code would need to be made available due to the GPL license, which is fine as it would be distributed via Wheels which already contain the source code, however, this is not planned and unlikely, it is meant to be used only internally and it is not meant to be a product to be sold, but rather a tool to be used internally.

There are probably many developers in the same scenario, be it with Python or any other language and its packages, developing tools for internal use, I would like to ask you how have you handled this in your company.

Comment: I don't think this is the best platform for this type of question. It asks for opinions about best practices, that make it (at least slightly) out-of-scope here. And then there are very different types of corporate environments, from large multinational to SME or even freelance programmer. And the solutions will be very different for each. My recommendation is that you do a web research with a term like 'best practices gpl compliance' to see what is recommended in different areas.